# Passing data from one UITableView to another UITableView inside didSelectRow?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

There are two `UITableView`s, first one has a cell which when tapped, opens a second `UITableView`. When a cell in second `UITableView` is selected, the second tableView screen should dismiss and carry the text from that cell and populate the label in the first `UITableView`'s cell label. The code I have so far is as follows and it gives a threading error:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let destVC = EnrollmentAccountTableViewController()
    destVC.lblAccountType.text = GlobalParams.enrollmentAccountTypes[indexPath.row].acctName

    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :-

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: 
 IndexPath) {

  for obj in (self.navigationController?.viewControllers)! {
        if obj is EnrollmentAccountTableViewController {
 let vc2: EnrollmentAccountTableViewController =  obj as! EnrollmentAccountTableViewController
  vc2.strAccname = GlobalParams.enrollmentAccountTypes[indexPath.row].acctName
            _ =  
self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc2, animated: true)
 break
        }
    }

   }
```

in your EnrollmentAccountTableViewController

```
var  strAccname:String!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
 if  strAccname !=  nil {
  self.lblAccountType.text =  strAccname
  }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @PushpendraMishra your solution worked very well for me. Thanks again!

Comment: cannot accept for another 2 minutes. please up vote my question so at least it becomes zero. Thank you.